# Проблема с подключением файла

Tags: php, html, html5

Я подключил файл `style.css` в `header.php` и все работает нормально, но когда я захожу на другую страницу `pages/test.php`, где подключен `header.php` файл `style.css` не работает.

**Вот пример кода:**

*header.php*

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

*test.php*

```
require_once '../header.php';
```

Comment: Откройте в браузере консоль JS и посмотрите ошибки

Comment: @rjhdby Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Если вы открываете страницу из `pages/`, то ваш `css/style.css` превращается в `pages/css/style.css`. Используйте абсолютные пути.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте относительный путь от корня сайта

```
<link href="/css/style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```

Answer (score 0):

В head надо написать:

```
<base href='/'>
```

Такой проблемы больше не будет.

Comment: Проблема вылезет в другом месте, где надо будет подключать скрипты/стили из, например, текущего каталога страницы